# Can anybody help explain what happens here with Java thread interruption?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

These are the 3 classes I have:

```
public class ChildThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Child thread is running.");
            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("Child thread is interrupted.");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MainThread extends Thread{

    public Thread childThread = new ChildThread();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        childThread.start();
    }
}

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainThread mainThread = new MainThread();
        mainThread.start();
        mainThread.childThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

When I run this, the child thread doesn't seem to be ever interrupted. It keeps printing: "Child thread is running."
However, if I put a debug breakpoint at `mainThread.childThread.interrupt();`, child thread will get interrupted.

And also, if I change App class like the following:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ChildThread childThread = new ChildThread();
        childThread.start();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        childThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

it works again. Child thread gets interrupted and stopped printing after 3 seconds.

It seems that the behaviors are different interrupting from a thread that directly started a child thread, and from a thread that didn't directly start a child thread. And it's also different depending on whether there's a breakpoint or not. It's so weird to me. How could this work in a complex system? I don't think a complex system can guarantee all interruption signals are from the original starters of threads.

Could anyone help explain this? I can't find anywhere that seem to have an answer.

Comment: Not a solution... but it's sufficient to just call `isInterrupted()` because you're extending from the `Thread` class. Typically you don't extend from `Thread` - that's why you call `Thread.currentThread()`.

Comment: @JYun change them to Runnable, the result is the same. :(

Comment: @Enzokie I see what you mean. If I put mainThread.join(); to make sure mainThread.run() is called, it will work normally. Thank you so much! I now know Java again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the Thread.sleep before interrupting otherwise, you are interrupting before the child thread even before it has gotten a chance to start running. As per the API specs "Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect.". So, in affect, the interrupt statement is being ignored as at the time the thread is not active. Without the sleep, the thread become active AFTER the interrupt - hence is never interrupted.

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MainThread mainThread = new MainThread();
        mainThread.start();
        Thread.sleep(1);    // <== This line is needed as otherwise, the next line will 
                            //      interrupt the thread, even before it has started running!
        mainThread.childThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```